# Does RFID interfere with NFC

Tags: rfid, interference, nfc

i have a small question about interference. Do active RFID (860 MHz) interfere with NFC cards (13.56 Mhz) when placed on top of eachother? (NFC above RFID tag for example). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

RFID is a form of NFC (see ISO 14443 and 15693). They are on different frequency bands, so you you should be fine.

Comment: ISO documents aren't freely accessible, so your reference to them isn't helpful. Can you tell here what they're about?

Comment: @FedericoRusso you are right the documents are not freely available, but wikipedia has articles for [ISO 15693](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_15693) (contactless smartcards for high distance communication) and [ISO 14443](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_14443) (Identification cards / Contactless integrated circuit cards / Proximity cards)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that depends on the equipment you are using to read the tag(s) - and you need to test that.

What I can tell from personal experience that if the reader don't understand both standards - then no problem but if you for instance have a reader that can understand both then it will try and read both and fail.

With two readers one for rfid and one for nfc tags, we have had no problem with tags placed closely to each other; however I have only used tags - and my understanding is that they are passive.

Have not seen any issues when we are trying to use both readers but it is hard to say that we have managed to test that, our timing might have been slightly off when we tried doing those tests manually...